# htacces redirect with subdomain-change

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

After namechange of an navigation sub-topic we have to redirect all pages to the new subdomain:

Old: /max/sport/es-wird-besser

New: /max/geschichten/es-wird-besser

```
 redirectMatch 301 ^/max/sport$ /max/geschichten$1
```

Unfortunately it doesnt work proberly.

Answer (score 0):

Try with below, we are using matching groups.

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/max/sport/(.*)$ /max/geschichten/$1
```

Comment: @StillerEugen Sorry didn't get you.

Comment: sorry. 
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])/$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/max/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule .* /max/index.php?PERMA=$0 [QSA,L]
now it puts the PERMA= after the redirected link

Comment: tried to put the above code inside a RewriteRule (RewriteRule ^/max/sport/(.*)$ /max/geschichten/$1 [R=301,L]) but this doestn work

Comment: I don't understand what you are doing.

Comment: sorry,-) if i try your code it redirects to  /max/geschichten/es-wird-besser?PERMA=sport/es-wird-besser

Comment: the PERMA=.. comes from another rewriteRule later on the code.

Comment: and this: RewriteRule .* /max/index.php?PERMA=$0 [QSA,L]

Comment: Use this code before any other rule and use only this rule for your purpose don't use multiple rules to solve same problem.

Comment: how can i avoid this ?PERMA..inside the URL

Comment: Problem is, i need the second rewrite to works the full website. i have to match this to

Comment: Please provide the rules you are using currently.